# How do I inspect the filter chain in rails (3.0.8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, before-filter

Apparently [`#filter_chain`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/filter_chain) is deprecated, does anyone know how? I've tried several things, but can't really find anything that works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
YourController._process_action_callbacks
```

Comment: This was hanging for me in Rails 3.2, when called from a breakpoint in a controller method.  I ended up calling

`_process_action_callbacks.map(&:raw_filter)`  to see an array of the before_filter method names.